# How can I use dependency injections in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

This is my AuthService.How can I use this auth service in all my components. I want to maintain userLoggedIn value global for all my components.I am getting the below error, when I run this script - Property 'userLoggedIn' does not exist on type 'AuthService'.

```
import { Component, Input, Inject, ReflectiveInjector, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    static userLoggedIn : boolean = false;
    //call this function when login status changes
    static changeLoginStatus(status: boolean){
        this.userLoggedIn = status;
    }
}
```

Component file -

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, AbstractControl, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
//import './rxjs-operators';

import { CustomValidators } from '../common/validations.ts';
import { AuthService } from '../injectables/authservice.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm : FormGroup;
    data : any;
    //http : Http;

    constructor(private http: Http, fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.loginForm = fb.group({
      'email':[null, Validators.compose([Validators.required,CustomValidators.emailFormat])],
      'password':[null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    });
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    submitLoginForm(value: any){
        console.log(value);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        let body = JSON.stringify(value);

       this.http.post(
        'http://192.168.1.90/articles/data/post/',
        body)
      .subscribe((res: Response) => {
        this.data = JSON.stringify(res);
        console.log('---->'+res.json().data.email);
        localStorage.setItem('email', res.json().data.email);
        localStorage.setItem('userID', res.json().data.id);
        localStorage.setItem('name', res.json().data.name);
        localStorage.setItem('loginStatus', 'true');
        //this.loginStatus = true;
        //aService: AuthService;
        AuthService.changeLoginStatus(true);
        console.log('localstorege item ---->'+localStorage.getItem('email'));
      });
      return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service explains it well.
Questions should contain the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html

Comment: Just added code snippet. Can you please suggest me..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `AuthService` to

```
export class AuthService {
    userLoggedIn : boolean = false;
    changeLoginStatus(status: boolean){
        this.userLoggedIn = status;
    }
}
```

Dependency injection works through your `constructor` parameter. Any component which use `AuthService` should have it in its `constructor` parameter, for example

```
constructor(
   private myAuthService: AuthService, // <-- here
   private http: Http, 
   fb: FormBuilder
) {
   // ...
}

submitLoginForm(value: any) {
   // ...
   this.myAuthService.changeLoginStatus(true); // <-- here
}
```

Also, make sure you use `AuthService` in your `NgModule` providers, for example :

```
@NgModule({
   // .....
   providers: [ AuthService ]   // <-- here
   // .....
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Still I am getting the same error. Now, this is my latest code.

    import { Component, Input, Inject, ReflectiveInjector, Injectable  } from '@angular/core';
    @Injectable()
    export class AuthService {
        static userLoggedIn : boolean = false;
        constructor(){}
        //call this function when login status changes
        static changeLoginStatus(status: boolean){
            AuthService.userLoggedIn = status;
        }
    }

I am calling this from component like this -

    AuthService.changeLoginStatus(true);

Comment: @vasanthkumar, can you post your component code which use that service?

Comment: Just posted my component. Can you check it once

Comment: Added same way you said in the comment. but still getting same error. I can't understand what's wrong..

I already added AuthService in providers in @NgModule as well

Error Msg - Property 'userLoggedIn' does not exist on type 'AuthService'.

Comment: @vasanthkumar why are you using `static` for `userLoggedIn` ?

Comment: Changed my service file to like this. It worked. Just removed static variable and called the variable inside menthod with this operator

export class AuthService {
    userLoggedIn : boolean = false;
    changeLoginStatus(status: boolean){
        this.userLoggedIn = status;
    }
}

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @vasanthkumar good to know. Will add your code to the answer for clarity. Thank You.